# Makefile - build from multiple directories

Tags: makefile, build, compilation

I am new to Makefile.

I have a string of multiple directories and I want to compile all the .c files in them.
The number of paths in that string can change (it is received as an argument from a script).
For example:
DIRS = path1 path2...

I will be happy to receive help with building a mechanism that can go over DIRS and compile each and every .c file in each path.

I am not sure if this is the right way, but I got this so far:

---

```
DIRS = path1 path2

define generateRules
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(path)/*.c)

%.o: $(SOURCES)
    echo "path is $(path)";
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${INCS} ${DEFS} -c $< -o ${BUILD}/$@
endef

$(foreach path,$(DIRS),$(info $(generateRules)))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with generating a list of the source files.

```
DIRS = path1 path2
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.c,$(DIRS)))
```

From this we can generate a list of targets:

```
TARGETS = $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD)/%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))
```

The simplest way to get the effect you want is by use of the [vpath directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) and a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
vpath %.c $(DIRS)

$(TARGETS): $(BUILD)/%.o: %.c
    @echo building $@ from $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ${INCS} ${DEFS} -c $< -o $@
```

If you want to generate a rule for each source directory -- or each source file -- you can, but that requires a few more advanced techniques. I advise you to get the simple approach working first.